# Gitlab backups have recently ballooned

Tags: backup, gitlab

I've installed and am running Gitlab via Omnibus installation.
For years my Gitlab backups have hovered around 1 gigabyte, total. Over the last year or so though, they have ballooned in size and now a single backup is almost 40 gigabytes.
Needless to say, this is disconcerting. I've done my due diligence, but even by manually tallying the size of all my repos and the database there's no way I reach 40 gigabytes of data.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know for sure with the information you provided (how have you tried to troubleshoot this issue?), but it's possible that gitlab is storing all the `artifacts` from previous `jobs`.

In any case, I suggest running a command like `du -s | sort -n -r` in your github installation folder to see which directory is the biggest, and what's inside.

Comment: This in a roundabout way led me to the fix. 
Backups were supposed to be copied to an NFS share. But that copy failed, causing the backup process to fail, causing Gitlab to never clean up the backup dir. That then started bloating. 
Manually clearing out the backup dir and fixing the nfs share permissions fixed the problem.